# WKwebview not showing up with activity indicator

Tags: ios, swift, progress

I am trying to load a web page in a `WKWebView`. It actually worked fine. However, i have been having problems getting the progress indicator (`UIActivityIndicaatorView()`) to show up. I cant figure out what am doing wrong. I have tried so many solutions. Please help

```
    var activityIndicator:UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    var webView:WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Setting up webview
        let webConfiguraton = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguraton)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(webView)
        let myURL = URL(string:"link")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
        webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.isLoading), options: .new, context: nil)
        // setting up activity indicator
        activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
        view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "loading"{
            if webView.isLoading{

            } else {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: why you are not adding web view as subview of main view. You are assigning web view to the view. Thats why the activity indicator is not showing up. Try to setup the web view in viewdidload and add it as subview.

Comment: i did what you said. The indicator now shows but the wkwebview no longer shows. Forgive me, am just a beginner

Comment: I am also a beginner :). Give you web view a size. You are giving it zero size. Give view.bounds instead of .zero.

Answer (score 0):

`WKWebView` seems that is not showing up because you are setting its `frame` size to `.zero`. You could try to set it like so:

```
webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: webConfiguraton)
```